# How to replace all "/" with "\" in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Tried following ways,

```
            def str1 = "/home/test-data/"
    def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\/','\\')
            println str2
```

Error in Console : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1

```
             def str1 = "/home/test-data/"
    def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\/','\')
            println str2
```

Error in script : Remove unnecessary semicolons

```
            def str1 = "/home/test-data/"
    def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\/','\')
            println str2
```

Prints like this in console : 'home'test-data'

Answer (score 4):

Your answer:

```
def str1 = "/home/test-data/"
def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\/','\\\\')
println str2
```

in reverse:

```
def str1 = "\\home\\test-data\\"
def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\\\','/')
println str2
```

Comment: Any suggestions for this,  def str1 = "\home\test-data\"
  def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\\','\///')
    println str2

Comment: @ Cliff - Can you please help me with other way replace option, from '\' to '/'

Answer (score 3):

You need 4 backslashes instead of 2. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2225